# How to let sendmail preserve plus detail for .forward?

Tags: sendmail

I have a normal sendmail installation. A user has a `.forward` like this:

```
# cat ~elrond/.forward
elrond@somewhere
# sendmail -bv elrond+extra@localhost
elrond@somewhere...  deliverable: mailer esmtp, host somewhere., user elrond@somewhere
```

Note that the `+extra` is lost.

What do I need to change to make the `+extra` be preserved? The usual `%3` for hashmaps does not work in the `.forward`.

Comment: Could you post results of `sendmail -bv elrond+extra@localhost` **without** `~elrond/.forward` file? [There are some special cases]

Comment: Gives a nice and easy `elrond+extra@this.box... deliverable: mailer local, host extra, user elrond`. But please give all variants in your hopefully upcoming answer, so that others with other variants will love that answer too.

Comment: Could you post also which program your sendmail uses as local mailer? `P=xxx` after Mlocal line in your sendmail.cf. I have hoped for `host extra` because it most likely will simplify things a lot. I am not too good at brief explanations of advanced sendmailing ;-)

Comment: Well, does the `Mlocal` have *any* effect when `.forward` is in effect? I highly doubt that. For the record: I have `FEATURE(local_procmail)`. So it's procmail in the `Mlocal` line.

Comment: Is there indeed a usernamed 'elrond+extra' in your system?????  Also, I strongly recommend reading the document concerning creation of the *.mc file for sendmail.

Comment: @mdpc: There's only a user elrond. The `+detail` is a feature of sendmail. If you have a user elrond, you will receive any mail on `elrond+FOOBAR` for any `FOOBAR`. And I am writing .mc files for about 15 years now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`FEATURE(preserve_local_plus_detail)`](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/features.html#preserve_local_plus_detail) in your `.mc` file, and rebuild your `.cf`.
This modifies ruleset 5 (`localaddr`). It may cause side-effects (i.e. if your local mailer doesn't support +detail).

If this adversely effects your aliases lookup, then perhaps `_FFR_ALIAS_DETAIL` is for you, this is a build time (i.e. not `.cf`) option, I can't say I've tested it though. Not recommended ;-)

Failing that, the only way I can see of doing anything like you require with just user-controlled `.forward` files is to check your `confFORWARD_PATH` includes a path that has a `$h` component. This should be the default since at least 8.12:

```
O ForwardPath=$z/.forward.$w+$h:$z/.forward+$h:$z/.forward.$w:$z/.forward
```

This will allow a users to create say, `~/.forward.extra` to control where "user+extra" addressed email goes:

```
$ sendmail -v -d27.2  -bv elrond+foo 
alias(elrond+foo)
alias(elrond+*)
alias(elrond)
alias(elrond)
forward(elrond+foo)
include(/home/elrond/.forward.thishost+foo)
include(/home/elrond/.forward+foo)
include(/home/elrond/.forward.thishost)
include(/home/elrond/.forward)
elrond+foo... deliverable: mailer local, host foo, user elrond
```

(You can see the forward files being handled by the `include()` function ‒ it has no notion of expansion when it reads the files.)

`FEATURE(virtusertable)` as suggested elsewhere is probably a better way to go, if you're the scripting kind you could collect user `~/.xforward` files periodically and build a master virtusertable.

Comment: Good idea! I haven't seen that option. BUT: From the docs "Preserve the +detail portion of the address when passing address to local delivery agent. Disables alias and .forward +detail stripping (e.g., given user+detail, only that address will be looked up in the alias file; user+* and user will not be looked up)" -- Well, this basicly means, that sendmail -bv elrond+extra@localhost gives a "user unknown". And I wonder, if it really would forward to elrond+extra@somewhere in that case?

Answer (score 1):

You use procmail as sendmail's local mailer program [`FEATURE(local_procmail)`]
=> you may redirect/forward messages in ~elrond/.procmailrc with $1 holding the detail part.

Sorry but my procmail knowledge is insufficient to provide RELIABLE recipe e.g. some sanity checks of $1.

***WARNING:*** message to both elrond+1 and elrond+2 will be passed as two separate messages to procmail.

Comment: Okay, that would be an option. But I would like to keep the envelope sender of the mail (.forward would do that). Yes, I could extract the envelope sender in procmail (I actually have that for very specific things working). But really, I would like something for all my system user's to work. So that I can tell them "If you want to forward with detail, put `{yourname}%3@{yourhost}` in your own `.forward`.

Comment: Are you interested in postmaster level solutions? e.g. virtusertable entry.

Comment: `virtusertable` is the one place, where this whole thing works nicely: `elrond@this.box elrond%3@other.box`. I have that in place for some of my users without system accounts (also I find it stupid, that virtuser can't take entries without domain, as this box has multiple domains and adding them all to virtusertable is ugly). For system users I would really prefer them being able to _easily_ edit their own forwarding. That said, I will probably resort to letting users tell me, what they want and me adding multiple entries to `virtusertable`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered allowing users use (dovecot) sieve?

It seems that you may use example below with `redirect` instead of `fileinto`
http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Examples#Plus_Addressed_mail_filtering